# How to write if elseif else condition laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Below is my query,

```
rows = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE score = 1"
if (rows.Count < 3) //at least one row
return if;
else if(rows.Count >7)
return 'else if';
else
return 'else';
```

How to write above query with when using querybuilder laravel. Actually I want to know about how to write else condition.

Below is my code;

```
$query=DB::table('aaa')
->select('*')
->when($count<3,function ($q){
    echo 'if';
})
->when($count>7,function ($q){
    echo 'else if';
})

///I dont know how to write else condition here
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far? What kind of logic are you applying in the conditions? You can count all the rows beforehand, and use `when()`, for example.

Comment: Yes, I wrote when condition for if and else if condition, but i dont know about how to write else condition with when. can you help me @Qirel

Comment: It's just a third `when()` with the boolean conditions of the if and elseif conditions, inverse.

Comment: I added my code . Can you write answer for me @Qirel

Comment: you can use when.. example `Model::select("*", \DB::raw('(CASE  WHEN users.status = "0" THEN "User"  WHEN users.status = "1" THEN "Admin" ELSE "SuperAdmin"  END) AS status_lable'))->get();`

Comment: I want to use when clause for condtions @noor

Comment: please chek [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)..

Comment: This is only if and else condition and this is used in single clause of when what about if, else if and else condtion @noor

Comment: @noor Great example, but it will only work for `if/else`, not for `if/elseif/else`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no `else` counterpart to `when()` when using multiple conditions (`if/elseif/else`), but if you think of it, it's just the inverse of the sum of the other conditions. To exactly mirror a PHP `if/elseif/else`, you need to check the first condition, and then explicitly check the second condition *and not* the first condition, and to mimic the `else` condition, its just whichever boolean condition is needed when all else conditions fails.

```php
$query = DB::table('table')
           ->select('*')
           ->when($count < 3, function ($q) {
               // if count < 3
           })
           ->when($count > 7, function ($q) {
               // else if count > 7
           })
           ->when($count =< 7 && $count >= 3, function($q) {
               // Else, count between 3 and 7 (inclusive)
           });
```

You can conditionally apply a where clause "manually" by using native PHP `if/elseif/else` controls and apply a simple `where()`, which might be more explicit if your conditions become very expressive or complex.

There is however an `else` condition when you have a simple `if/else`, as you can provide it another closure. This cannot be used with multiple conditions, as you've originally asked about, but I included it for reference.

```php
$query = DB::table('table')
           ->select('*')
           ->when($count < 3, function ($q) {
               // if count < 3
           }, function($q) {
               // Else, count greater or equal to 3
           });
```

Answer (score 3):

May be this is what you are seeking for :

```
$query=DB::table('aaa');

if($count < 3) {
    $query->where('quantity', '>=',  $count);
}
 
if($count < 7) {
    $query->where('quantity', '>', $count);
}

$query = $query->get();
```

Comment: I want to use when clause not to put simple if else

Answer (score 0):

```
$role = $request->input('role');
 
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->when($role, function ($query) use ($role) {
                return $query->where('role_id', $role);
             })
             ->get();
```